# Размеры для медиа-адаптации на CSS

Tags: css

Всем привет, учу медиа-адаптацию на css для различных диагоналей и разрешений экранов. Есть ли стандарные размеры для медиа-адаптации? Понятно, что устройств многожество и тп, однако мне нужен список основных размеров (min-width, max-width, min-height, max-height) для начальной работы с ними, которые будут захватывать основные размеры экранов смартфонов, планшетов и т.д. без "серых зон" между ними.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не существует точного списка стандартных размеров для всех устройств, потому что их банально слишком много.
Вот примерные значения которые я видел чаще всего:
Смартфоны (вертикальная ориентация): до 767 пикселей, (горизонтальная ориентация): 768 до 991 пикселей.
Планшеты: 992 до 1199 пикселей.
Небольшие ноутбуки и десктопы: 1200 до 1439 пикселей.
Большие десктопы: 1440 пикселей и выше.
А лучше используй относительные единицы измерения (проценты, em, rem) для лучшей гибкости.